# Using Fluture with AWS Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, fluture

I'm using a fluture to handle the response from an AWS service request.

I get the expected response using a callback or a Promise wrapped around the callback. When I try to use a fluture, looks like I am getting back a regurgitation of the request. Gotta be something stoopid... (again)

```
const Rekognition = require ('aws-sdk/clients/rekognition');
const rekognition = new Rekognition ({
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

const fs = require ('fs');
const Future = require ('fluture');


const imageBytes = fs.readFileSync ('../data/image.jpg');


const params = {
    Image: {
        Bytes: imageBytes
    }
};

const detectText = Future((rej, res) =>
    rekognition.detectText(params, (err, data) => err ? rej(err) : res(data)));

detectText.fork(console.error, console.log);
```

Expected results:
{ TextDetections:
   [ { DetectedText: 'text1',
       Type: 'LINE',
       Id: 0,
       Confidence: 98.7948989868164,
       Geometry: [Object] },
     { DetectedText: 'text2',...

Actual results:
c5GeDWkmkn3ZpFJK/UszSxBOCN2AR7Gs0uqtHlSDuGHX+EnuakC43xxqN6ABWY/e+lRiOaNrg+UWKqGAHfii0bXZv...

Comment: I'm not sure exactly from your description what the question is, but I can spot one mistake in there: you're not returning a cancellation function into `Future()`. You're probably better off using `detectText = Future.node(done => rekognition.detectText(params, done))`, which doesn't need a cancellation function.

Comment: I think if I enclose the body of that function in braces, it will achieve the desired result. I haven't had time to test this yet on this specific piece of code, but I noticed I had problems on some other stuff I was doing without the braces. IOW, the code would look like this:
```const detectText = Future((rej, res) => {
    rekognition.detectText(params, (err, data) => err ? rej(err) : res(data))}); ```